# Backbone collection view code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working on a simple backbone `.js` scipt. I have a collection of Views which is formed using a Model View. Here is the Model View :

```
//model view
 App.Views.Task = Backbone.View.extend({

    //receives model instance      
    tagName : 'li',    
    template : _.template($('#taskTemplate').html()),

    render : function() {     
       this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));       
       return this;     
    }    
 });
```

Now the problem is that my code works if I write the collection view like this:

```
//collection view
 App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({

    //receives collection instance
    tagName : 'ul',

    initialize : function(){ this.render() },

    render : function(){      
        this.collection.each(function(tas){
            var t = new App.Views.Task({model : tas});
            this.$el.append(t.render().el);
        }, this);      
    }     
 });
```

Then `console.log(theview.el)` code is ok.

But if I write it like this is not working:

```
 //collection view
 App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({

    //receives collection instance      
    tagName : 'ul',

    render : function(){
        this.collection.each(function(tas){
            var t = new App.Views.Task({model : tas});
            this.$el.append(t.render().el);
            return this;
        }, this);    
    }    
 });
```

For this code `console.log(theview.render().el)` throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined .

Why is that ?

Comment: Why are you returning this inside of the each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a  `return` statement inside your loop. You can only return one result.

```
render : function(){
  this.collection.each(function(tas){
    var t = new App.Views.Task({model : tas});
    this.$el.append(t.render().el);
  },this);

  return this;
}
```

Comment: Thank's Hazaart. I was so stupid...obvious the return is braking the loop. Have a nice day !